# What version of log4j did %c{1.} become valid

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I would like to use the following Conversion Pattern

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1.}:%L - %m%n
```

Which produces output like

```
2016-06-08 10:29:40 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG h.d.h.l.l.s.w.f.MyClass:27 - This is a debug message.
2016-06-08 10:29:40 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] INFO  h.d.h.l.l.s.w.f.MyClass:22 - This is an info message.
2016-06-08 10:29:40 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] WARN  h.d.h.l.l.s.w.f.MyClass:33 - This is a warn message.
2016-06-08 10:29:40 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR h.d.h.l.l.s.w.f.MyClass:39 - This is an error message.
2016-06-08 10:29:40 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] FATAL h.d.h.l.l.s.w.f.MyClass:45 - This is a fatal message.
```

However when I run my tests and trigger my log4j file I get the error message

```
log4j:ERROR Category option "1." not a decimal integer.
```

Log4j and slf4j are setup in my pom with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.19</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

What version of log4j do I need to get 1. to be a valid Category option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using PatternLayout not EnhancedPatternLayout

```
%c{1.}
```

Is only available in EnhancedPatternLayout

Comment: `%c{1.}` see [javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html)

Comment: I'm about 4 years behind you, but your follow up helped me.  Thank you.